# Python django paginator not displaying items correctly

Tags: python, django, pagination

I developed a simple web app. I have added the paginate_by property to the view. I'm able to show only the first 10 records retrived from the database. If i change the paginate_by property to 20 I always see 10 records in the list page of my models. Note that the number or records change in the top bottom left of the screenshot but I always see 10 records.
Here the code:

views.py:

```
class DeviceList(LoginRequiredMixin, FilterView):
    model = models.Device
    filterset_class = filters.DeviceFilter
    context_object_name = "devices"
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = "device_list.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DeviceList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["hist_devices"] = (models.Device.objects.filter(history_type=0)).count()
        context["active_devices"] = (
            models.Device.objects.filter(history_type=1)
        ).count()
        context["available_devices"] = (models.Device.objects.filter(status=0)).count()
        context["unavailable_devices"] = (
            models.Device.objects.filter(status=1)
        ).count()
        return context
```

device_list.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load pagination_tags %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css">
{% block title %}
Device list
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h2>Device list</h2>
<div class="row row-no-gutters">
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="accordion accordion" id="accordionFlushExample">
         <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header">
               <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne">
                  <h5>Filters</h5>
               </button>
            </h2>
            <div id="flush-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
               <div class="accordion-body">
                  <form method="get">
                     {{ filter.form.as_p }}
                     <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
                  </form>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="card card-body">
            <h5><i class="bi bi-stop-fill"></i> Export devices</h5>
            <hr>
            <h1><a href="{% url 'export_devices' %}">Export</a></h1>
            </div>
      </div>
   </div>
<br>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <div class="card card-body">
            <h5><i class="bi bi-play-fill"></i> Total active Devices</h5>
            <hr>
            <h1>{{ active_devices }}</h1>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <div class="card card-body">
            <h5><i class="bi bi-stop-fill"></i> Total historic devices</h5>
            <hr>
            <h1>{{ hist_devices }}</h1>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <br>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <div class="card card-body">
            <h5><i class="bi bi-pause-fill"></i> Total available devices</h5>
            <hr>
            <h1>{{ available_devices }}</h1>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <div class="card card-body">
            <h5><i class="bi bi-pause-fill"></i> Total unavailable devices</h5>
            <hr>
            <h1>{{ unavailable_devices }}</h1>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="table-responsive">
   <table id="sortedtable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive" data-sort-name="field_id"
      data-sort-order="asc">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th data-field='field_id'>Id</th>
            <th data-filed='field_user_history'>User History</th>
            <th data-field='field_company'>Company</th>
            <th data-field='field_department'>Department</th>
            <th data-field='field_office'>Office</th>
            <th data-field='field_status'>Status</th>
            <th data-field='field_history_type'>History</th>
            <th data-field='field_serial_number'>Serial Number</th>
            <th data-field='field_contract'>Contract</th>
            <th data-field='field_expiration_date'>Expiration date</th>
            <th data-field='field_renewal_date'>Renewal date</th>
            <th data-field='field_host_name'>Host name</th>
            <th data-field='field_make'>Make</th>
            <th data-field='field_model'>Model</th>
            <th data-field='field_place'>Place</th>
            <th data-field='field_user'>User</th>
            <th data-field='field_detail'>Detail</th>
            <th data-field='field_delete'>Delete</th>
            <th data-field='field-edit'>Edit</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         {% for device in devices  %}
         <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{ device.id }}</th>
            <td>
               {% for usr in device.user_history.all %}
               {{ usr }}<br />
               {% endfor %}
            </td>
            <td>{{ device.company }}</td>
            <td>{{ device.department }}</td>
            <td>{{ device.office }}</td>
            <td>{{ device.get_status_display }}</td>
            <td>{{ device.get_history_type_display }}</td>
            <td>{{ device.serial_number }}</td>
            <td>{{ device.contract }}</td>
            <td>{{ device.expiration_date|date:"d/m/Y" }}</td>
            <td>{{ device.renewal_date|date:"d/m/Y" }}</td>
            <td>{{ device.host_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ device.make }}</td>
            <td>{{ device.model }}</td>
            <td><a href="{% url 'place_detail' device.place.id %}">
               {{ device.place }}</a>
            </td>
            {% if device.user %}
            <td><a href="{% url 'user_detail' device.user.id %}">
               {{ device.user.name }} {{ device.user.surname }}</a>
            </td>
            {% else %}
            <td>
               {{ device.user.name }} {{ device.user.surname }}
            </td>
            {% endif %}
            <td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'device_detail' device.id %}">Detail
               </a>
            </td>
            <td><a class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'device_delete' device.id %}">Delete</a>
            </td>
            <td><a class="btn btn-success" href="{% url 'update_device' device.id %}">Edit</a>
            </td>
         </tr>
         {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
    {% if is_paginated %}
        <nav aria-label="Navigation">

            <ul class="pagination">
                {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?{% url_replace request 'page' 1 %}">&laquo;
                        first</a></li>
                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link"
                                             href="?{% url_replace request 'page' page_obj.previous_page_number %}">previous</a>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}



                {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link"
                                             href="?{% url_replace request 'page' page_obj.next_page_number %}">next</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link"
                                             href="?{% url_replace request 'page' page_obj.paginator.num_pages %}">last
                        &raquo;</a></li>
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <span class="current">
            Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}
        </span>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

url.py

```
from . import views
from .views import SearchResultsListView
urlpatterns = [
    path("device/create", views.create_device, name="device_register"),
    path("", views.DeviceList.as_view(), name="device_list"),
...
```

If I use 10 in paginate_by I get this in the object counter, 207 as total number of pages:

[image]

If I use 20 in paginate_by I get this in the object counter, 104 as total number of pages but only 10 records are shown:
[image]

It seems like the table is hiding 10 of the 20 rows I'm asking for. I would like to increase the records list on the single page, at least 20 rows in the table.

Can someone help me? I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Can someone help me? I don't know which way to turn.